# Realm indexOf()

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a recyclerview populated by a Realm db, with an option to duplicate an item in the list.
The kicker here is that the newly added duplicate may not always appear directly below the chosen item.
In normal circumstances one would use

```
int position = mList.indexOf(duplicate);
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
```

It seems indexOf, from the AbstractList class, is not supported in Realm,

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: indexOf is not supported on RealmResults
>   at io.realm.RealmResults.indexOf(RealmResults.java:183)

What would be another solution? 
( WITHOUT using mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() )

Comment: We just created an issue for this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2203 . Before we supportit , i think you can just use @LukaJ 's workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use a classic For-loop and return the index if the Item matches? 
ie

```
for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++){
    if (mList.get(i).equals(duplicate)){
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, that would be the method that would require most computation given a list of 200+ items, was wondering if there was any other way. If not I'd go with this one.

Comment: I used your method, seems there isn't any other method close to indexOf() in RealmLists... thanks

Comment: Yeah, I took a quick look through the documentation and there doesn't seem to be a more elegant solution right now, sorry.